# JSON format error when I send it using POST method

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, api, express

I have problems with "format" in my json post

I have an form in HTML-Angular like this

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit="processForm()">
    <input name="names" ng-model="userInfo.names" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="userInfo.lastName"  type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="city" ng-model="userInfo.personals.city" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="cellNumber" ng-model= "userInfo.personals.cellNumber" type="text" required>
    <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select" ng-model="userInfo.personals.area">
        <option value="1">OP1</option>
        <option value="2">OP2</option>
        <option value="3">OP3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Post</button>
</form>
```

My controller is

```
function mainCTRL ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, notify, $http) {
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http.post('/register', $scope.userInfo).success(function(res){console.log(res);});
    };
}
```

My problem is when my api gets the JSON, it looks like

```
{
    names: "name",
    lastname: "last",
    personals: {
        city: "city",
        cellNumber: "12345",
        area: ['1','2']
    }
}
```

And I try to save it in a model

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    var perfil = new Perfiles(req.body);
    perfil.save(function(err, perfil){
         if(err){return next(err);}
            res.json(perfil);
    });
});
```

But it show me an 500 error. If I send a post using Postman the request format is diferent and is available to save

```
{
        names: "name",
        lastname: "last",
        personals.city: "city",
        personals.cellNumber: "12345",
        personals.area: ['1','2']
        }
  }
```

[image]

Whats is the diference between both methods?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, there are two data type of request: form type and json type.

So it is necessary for you to determine the type of request data when posting like this.

```
$http({
    data: $scope.userInfo,
    method: "POST",
    url: "/register",
    headers: {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
}).then(function mySucces(res) {
   console.log(res);
});
```

And the reason why the result of Postman is different from one of the website is just that you have missed the data type selection of POSTMAN.

Please try to select the type as following and send again.
[image]

You can get the json value from the html form when submitting.

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit="processForm(userInfo)">
    <input name="names" ng-model="userInfo.names" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="userInfo.lastName"  type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="city" ng-model="userInfo.personals.city" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="cellNumber" ng-model= "userInfo.personals.cellNumber" type="text" required>
    <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select" ng-model="userInfo.personals.area">
        <option value="1">OP1</option>
        <option value="2">OP2</option>
        <option value="3">OP3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Post</button>
</form>
```

....

```
$scope.processForm = function(userInfo) {
  console.log(userinfo);
}
```